# How to reshape matrices in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When manipulating matrices it is often convenient to change their shape. For instance, to turn an N x M sized matrix into a vector of length N X M. In MATLAB a *reshape* function exists:

> RESHAPE(X,M,N) returns the M-by-N matrix whose elements are taken columnwise from X.  An error results if X does not have M*N elements.

In the case of converting between a matrix and vector I can use the Mathematica function *Flatten* which takes advantage of Mathematica's nested list representation for matrices. As a quick example, suppose I have a matrix X:

[image: 4x4 matrix]

With *Flatten*[X] I can get the vector {1,2,3,...,16}. But what would be far more useful is something akin to applying Matlab's *reshape*(X,2,8) which would result in the following Matrix:

[image: 4x4 matrix]

This would allow creation of arbitrary matrices as long as the dimensions equal N*M. As far as I can tell, there isn't anything built in which makes me wonder if someone hasn't coded up a Reshape function of their own.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Reshape[mtx_, _, n_] := Partition[Flatten[mtx], n]
```

Answer (score 13):

[ArrayReshape](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayReshape.html) does exactly that.

Comment: note this wasnt available when the question was asked, but is likely the best answer today.. (new in version 9)

Comment: @george yes; that's in the spirit of the site to promote adaptive answers!

Answer (score 5):

```
Reshape[list_, dimensions_] := 
First[Fold[Partition[#1, #2] &, Flatten[list], Reverse[dimensions]]]
```

Example Usage:

```
In: Reshape[{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3}]

Out: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

This works with arrays of arbitrary depth.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but for the sake of the archives and google searches I've got a more general way that allows a length m*n*... list to be turned into an m*n*... array:

```
Reshape[list_, shape__] := Module[{i = 1},
  NestWhile[Partition[#, shape[[i]]] &, list, ++i <= Length[shape] &]
  ]
```

Eg:

```
In:= Reshape[Range[8], {2, 2, 2}]

Out:= {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
```

Comment: Note: This solution transposes the last two dimensions, so it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

There is now also a new function ArrayReshape[].

Example:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} // MatrixForm

ArrayReshape[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {3, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: how do i reshape by column? i.e., elements go down vertically then move into the next column?